# Passar parametros da view para o criador de formulários Django

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django

Tenho a seguinte aplicação onde é suposto ser possivel editar os detalhes de uma determinada sala selecionada.  No ficheiro que trata a view faço a consulta à base de dados da sala selecionada para ediçao e quero passar esses detalhes para o construtor de formulários para ser postos como placeholders. A solução que tenho atualmente é a seguinte:

view.py

```
def editar_espaco(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        r=request.POST['espaco_edit']
        for regist in sala.objects.all():
            if regist.designacao_sala == r:
                form = editForm(piso=regist.piso,lotacao=regist.lotacao,laboratorio=regist.laboratorio,auditorio=regist.auditorio,estado=regist.status)
                return render(request,'editar_espaco.html',{'form':form,'nome_sala':r} )
            return render(request,'espaco.html')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

TIPOS_SALA=(('1','Laboratório'),('2','Auditório'),('3','Normal'))

class editForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._piso = kwargs.pop('piso', None)
        self._lotacao = kwargs.pop('lotacao', None)
        self._laboratorio = kwargs.pop('auditorio', None)
        self._estado = kwargs.pop('estado', None)
        super(editForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    piso = forms.IntegerField(required=True,label='Piso',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder':self._piso}))
    lotacao = forms.IntegerField(required=True,label='Lotação',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder':self._lotacao}))

    if (self._laboratorio==True):
        tipo_sala = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,label='Tipo de Sala:',choices=TIPOS_SALA,widget=forms.ChoiceInput(attrs={'placeholder':choices(1)}))
    elif(self._auditorio==True):
        tipo_sala = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,label='Tipo de Sala:',choices=TIPOS_SALA,widget=forms.ChoiceInput(attrs={'placeholder':choices(2)}))
    else:
        tipo_sala = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,label='Tipo de Sala:',choices=TIPOS_SALA,widget=forms.ChoiceInput(attrs={'placeholder':choices(3)}))

    estado = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,label='Estado',choices(('0','Indisponivel'),('1','Disponivel')),widget=forms.ChoiceInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Disponivel'}))
```

É suposto o método `__init__` receber e guardar os argumentos porem em todas as linhas em que utilizo "`self`" para ir buscar o argumento ele apontame que "`self`" não está definido. Agradecia qualquer tipo de ajuda.Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é esta mesmo, sim é muito texto. Porém no cenário de abstração permite maior flexibilidade.

No caso do ModelForm você pode usar também a classe meta:

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter description here'}),
        }
```